# undefined method `stringify_keys' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "progress":String
```

I get this error when put in the `check_box_tag` status. How resolved?

```
<%= form_tag update_me_iteams_path, :method =>'put' do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  <% @iteams.each do |iteam| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= iteam.id %></td>
      <td><%= iteam.title %></td>
      <td><%= iteam.text %></td>
      <td><%= iteam.status %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', iteam_path(iteam) %></td>
      <td>
          <%= check_box_tag "id[]", iteam.id, "status[]", iteam.status %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag "Edit Checked" %> 
<% end %>
```

My def

```rb
def update_me
  @iteam = Iteam.find(params[:id])

  if CHECK_STATUS_I_DONT_KNOWN == '0' 
    Iteam.where(params[:id]).update_attribute(status: 'DONE')
  else
    Iteam.where(params[:id]).update_attribute(status: 'progress')
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_box_tag` signature is `check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag). You are passing `item.status` as options which is causing the error.

Unfortunately it is not clear to me what checkbox you are trying to create here - why do you have `"status[]"` there, is that for another checkbox? Or are you trying to pass two form params with a single checkbox - that's simply not gona work. I'd expect something more like:

```
check_box_tag "id[]", item.id
```

### EDIT:

You do not need to send `status` via the form, you already have it in your database. Update the form to have the above change and your action to:

```
def update_me
  @iteams = Iteam.where(id: params[:id])

  done_items = @iteams.where(status: 'DONE').pluck(:id)
  progress_items = @iteams.where(status: 'progress).pluck(:id)
  @iteams.where(id: done_items).update_all(status: 'progress')
  @iteams.where(id: progress_items).update_all(status: 'DONE')
end
```

Comment: I need to pass two parameters somehow. Help, please, is there an alternative?

Comment: So you want both status and id of the item? Why? Having id you can find the status, can't you? Not to mention it would be more secure, as the status can change in time and relying on the state at the time of form load might be a risk

Comment: please check my question description. I have updated it. I think you will understand what I want to do, please help

Comment: @Kais - Unfortunatelly it does not make it cleaner at all. `CHECK_STATUS_I_DONT_KNOWN` is a constant, so the condition is fixed. There's no loop over `iteams` and the code as written would. firstly, raise an exception as this is not how `where` works, and secondly, even when corrected would just update all the records with the same status.

Comment: Therefore, I ask for help .... I need help to do this, I cannot, therefore I ask for help.

Comment: I am unable to help you as I don't understand the actual problem you''re trying to solve. The exception you're receiving is not the problem, it's a symptom of a bigger issue. What is the expected behaviour here?

Comment: I select the lines with the help of checkboxes, then when I have selected everything, I click on the button. In these lines there are statuses, if this is progress, then it should change to done, if the done, then it should change to progress.

Comment: This is the first time I do something in general on ruby, so nothing works

Comment: use your code and get this error undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass

Comment: its work, thank you very very match